# Primefaces: Handling multiple DataTable Rows, Columns, cell

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I wanted to know if it is possible to select an entire row or column in the DataTable or DataGrid when making click with the mouse. I've tried to handle it in the ManagedBean apart and integrate a javascript to capture data and manage the columns and rows but without any results.

[image: table with selected parts]

Then, we need this actions on the table:

1. Column selection (It should get a string with the values of each cell for the entire column) RED
2. Cell selection (It should get the value of the cell and also, the number of the column and the number of the row where this cell is located) BLUE
3. Row selection (It should get a string with the values of each cell for the entire row) GREEN

Comment: Cool requirements. I will be waiting for ur codes :D